# MediaUriElement hangs till video complete

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player, mediaelement

I am creating a player using `MediaUriElement`. where i have a list of titles to play 
which is a mix of both Image and Video. content will change in List Box selection change event.

i am using `VisualBrush` to replicate the video by filling to a rectangle in the same window for a mirror effect.

While running the application video and image plays good after some one hour there is a 
delay in shifting from video to image. ie, if i select the next item in `ListBox` to play
then there is a delay like whole application hangs till the currently running video completes, then the selection change happens and the next title is playing in the player.

I don't know any particular reason for being like this.

Please help